# Bazel - ":target" does not have mandatory providers: 'TemplateVariableInfo'

Tags: bazel

I wanna create a toolchain in bazel for my genrule. I created a file named toolchain.bzl and the source in this file is this:

```
BarInfo = provider(
    fields = {
        "bar": "path to bar executable",
    },
    doc = "Defines a Bar toolchain based on an SDK",
)

def _bar_toolchain_impl(ctx):
    bar_info = ctx.attr.path
    platform_bar_info = platform_common.ToolchainInfo(
        bar_info = BarInfo(bar = bar_info),
    )
    return [platform_bar_info]

bar_toolchain = rule(
    implementation = _bar_toolchain_impl,
    attrs = {
        "path": attr.string(
            doc = "path to bar executable",
            mandatory = False,
        ),
    },
)
```

And I wrote this in BUILD file.

```
load(":toolchain.bzl", "bar_toolchain")

toolchain_type(
    name = "toolchain_type",
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)

bar_toolchain(
    name = "bar_toolchain",
    path = "/usr/local/bin/bar",
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)

toolchain(
    name = "bar_linux",
    target_compatible_with = [
        "@platforms//os:linux",
        "@platforms//cpu:x86_64",
    ],
    toolchain = "//:bar_toolchain",
    toolchain_type = "//:toolchain_type",
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)

genrule(
    name = "build_bar",
    srcs = glob(["**/*.bar"]),
    outs = ["a.sh"],
    cmd = """
        touch a.sh
    """,
    toolchains = ["//:toolchain_type"],
)
```

But when I run

> bazel build //:build_bar

I get this error

> '//:toolchain_type' does not have mandatory providers: 'TemplateVariableInfo'.

What can I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`genrule`'s [`toolchains` attribute](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/general.html#genrule) can only be used to gain access to toolchain-specific "make variables" that are substituted into the `genrule`'s command string. Since your toolchain declares no make variables, Bazel errors out. Defining toolchain make variables is described in [the make variables documentation](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/general.html#genrule).